# author year with natbib package

Tags: natbib

I use the natbib package, and my bibliography style is acm (small caps). I would like to have 'year' appearing right after the author name, but I get this error message:

> ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations.

I have checked that all the entries in my .bib file have a year. In addition, I made sure my .bib file is encoded in UTF-8, supported by natbib. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers,authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
blablabla
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{FinalVersion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know natbib at all, but aren't `numbers` and `authoryear` contradictory options?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: yes probably. If I only use `authoryear` it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try with just `\usepackage{natbib}` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `acm` bibliography style is not compatible with `natbib`. You can make it work with

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natib}
```

but this still does not give you access to `natbib`'s features. Hence, you should choose a different bibliography style. If you like numerical citations with the authors in small caps in the bibliography, I recommend `acmtrans` with `natbib`'s `numbers` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
blablabla
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acmtrans}
\bibliography{FinalVersion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed I can make acm work with only `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. However, if I try the same with `acmtrans`, I get the following error message:  _I couldn't open style file acmtrans.bst_

Comment: @chicoutimy You need to install the [acmtrans](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/acmtrans) package.

Comment: Excuse me but do you know in which folder I should install this package? I use a mac

Comment: I think I managed to install the acmtrans package. However, this doesn't solve my problem. I would like year to appear after author but the same message _Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations_ appears. Can someone help?

Comment: @chicoutimy installation depends on your TeX distribution. For example, if you use TeXLive you should have tlmgr for the job.

Comment: Run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`. Then it should show what you want.

Comment: It's weird because I have TexLive 2012, I have Texlive utility but I can't find my TexLive Package manager (tlmgr)

Comment: I can't make tlmgr to work, can anybody help me please?

Comment: @chicoutimy I don't use Mac OSX but it seems you are using MacTeX, and the TeXLive Utility should make installing packages simple.

Comment: Thanks @mafp I am now able to use tlmgr via the terminal. However, when I try to install acmtrans, I get _TeX Live 2012 is frozen forever and will no longer be updated (...) package acmtrans not present in package repository_. I guess I'll have to wait for the new version of TexLive (2013)..What a mission to have a author appear after year with small caps :)

Comment: @chicoutimy I just realized that `acmtrans` is considered non-free, so it is not contained in TeXLive. I'm afraid you need to install by hand. But that is easy: `acmtrans.bst` should go into `bibtex/bst/acmtrans/` in some TEXMF tree, preferably the local one. Mine is under `$HOME/texmf`, but that may differ in Mac OS. Don't forget to run `texhash` after copying, so BibTeX can find it.

Comment: Dear @mafp, I followed your advice and got acmtrans installed (running sudo texash to have it found by bibtex). It now works with author-year! Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated :)